# working with sammyjs typescript and systemjs

Tags: javascript, systemjs, typing, sammy.js, typescript1.8

I am trying to create a simple routing application using sammyjs written in Typescript and systemjs as module loader.

However facing issues with loading of sammy.

Below are the code snippets

**SystemJs Config**

```
System.config({
  transpiler: "typescript",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  map: {
    "knockout": "../bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout",
    "sammy": "../bower_components/sammy/lib/sammy",
    "jquery": "../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery"
  }
});
```

**Route Provider**

```
import { Route } from "./types";
import * as Sammy from "sammy"

export class RouteProvider {
    sammyApp: Sammy.Application;
    defaultRoute: string;

    constructor() {
  }

  configureRoutes = (routes: Array<Route>) => {        
    this.sammyApp = Sammy(() => {
        routes.map((_route: Route) => {
            this.sammyApp.get('#' + _route.path, (context) => {
                _route.callBack(context);
            });
        })
    });

    this.sammyApp.run('#' + this.defaultRoute);
  }
}
```

When i initialize the *RouteProvider* class and call *configureRoutes* method i am getting below error,

*Uncaught TypeError: Sammy is not a function*

I checked the network tab in the browser and sammy.js has been loaded. Also I am getting proper type definitions and there is no Typescript compilation error.

Comment: You import everything from "sammy" as the Sammy object, your function should be an attribute of that object, not the object itself, i.e. Sammy.someFunction()

Comment: console.log out what's inside the Sammy object, I'm sure you'll notice what's wrong

Comment: @Ozrix : i logged the Sammy object in console it is an object, Object {VERSION: "0.7.6", __useDefault: true} , not sure how to use it I looked into sammy [source file[(https://github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/lib/sammy.js) it seems exported Sammy object is a function

Comment: okay, can you post what it outputs?

Comment: @Ozrix : i logged the Sammy object in console it is an object, Object {VERSION: "0.7.6", __useDefault: true} , not sure how to use it I looked into sammy [source file[(github.com/quirkey/sammy/blob/master/lib/sammy.js) it seems exported Sammy object is a function –

Comment: ill try to replicate your issue at my workspace and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like this statement

```
import * as Sammy from "sammy"
```

actually converts the function into an object. By doing this instead

```
Sammy = require("sammy");
```

it works, i.e. Sammy outputs as a function. Hope this helps.

Comment: requiring sammy as above fails to load module, system.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Module not already loaded loading "sammy" as http://localhost:51652/bower_components/sammy/lib/sammy   **I noted that there is no js extension in the required url** I tried to use  meta tag to load it as amd, but no luck, meta: {
    '../bower_components/sammy/lib/sammy': {
      format: 'amd', 
      exports: 'Sammy', 
      deps: [
        'jquery'
      ]
    }

Comment: what does your typescript compiler (tsc) configuration look like? You need to use "compilerOptions": { "module": "system" } if you're using tsconfig.js, or tsc --module system

Comment: Here is the tsc options "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    }

Comment: sorry, im out of ammo. the require method worked for me, im not sure where to go from here, since your typescript config looks okay